# A button in ASP.NET-MVC/Datatables.net fails to work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm a bit confused because the google chrome browser shows no syntax errors. The button is rendered but doesn't work.

```
"render": function () {
     return "<a class='btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm' onclick= location.href = '@Url.Action("InterfaceRuntime", "Interface")'><i class='fas fa-play-circle'></i> Run</a>";
},
```

edited:

thanks to the good advise I've tried the escape characters and it worked perfectly fine for me.

```
"render": function () {
    return "<a class='btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm' onclick= \" location.href = '@Url.Action("InterfaceRuntime", "Interface")'\"><i class='fas fa-play-circle'></i> Run</a>"; 
},
```

Comment: Look at the *rendered* HTML for any obvious errors in the rendered HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add quotes around the onclick code, like in the example below:

```
"render": function () {
    return "<a class='btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm' onclick=\"location.href = '@Url.Action("InterfaceRuntime", "Interface")'\""><i class='fas fa-play-circle'></i> Run</a>";
},
```

If this does not solve the problem, open the chrome developer console and look if there are any errors.